# Jquery issue on select option

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

need an help on a jquery script.
I have a select that trigger from Ajax a list of options available. Once user click this option if a variable got 1 a HTML div is added, if i change to another value HTML disappear. This script work as well first time: i click a option and div appear, when i click other option disappear but this cycle is completed if i it another time select option this stop working...
This is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { 
        request_url = 'opzioni-select';
    $.ajax({
        url: request_url,
        success: function(data){
            $('#id_opzione').html("");
            $.each(data, function(i, item){
                var id = item.id;
                var parent_id = item.parent;
                var nome_opzione = item.nome_opzione;
                var nome_parent = item.nome_parent;
                $('#id_opzione').append('<option data-opzione="'+ item.nome_parent +'" data-parent="'+ item.parent +'" id="' + item.nome_opzione +'" value="' + item.id + '">' + item.nome_opzione +'</option>');

            });
            $(document).on('change', '.opzione', function(){
                    var parent = $('#id_opzione').find(':selected').data('parent');
                    var nome_parent = $('#id_opzione').find(':selected').data('opzione');
                    if(parent != null) {
                        $('#parent-div').append('<label for="parent-div" class=" control-label col-md-4 text-left">'+ nome_parent +'</label><div class="col-md-6"><input type="text" name="valore_parent" class="form-control"></div><div class="col-md-2"></div>');
                    } else {
                        $('#parent-div').hide('fast');
                    }

                });
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

I tried to change div id in class and switched to "on('change" instead of call directly the #div with .change( but nothing.

Comment: Move the `$(document).on('change',` part outside the `$.ajax` call.  You're adding a new event handler every time you make the ajax call.  If it wasn't a delegated event handler it would probably be ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few problems - you're appending a bunch of options - then delegating for a class that i cant see being created.. Id recommend moving the delegated event to the document ready function. . and using the id of the select - and selecting the option after that using `this`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { 
        request_url = 'opzioni-select';
    $.ajax({
        url: request_url,
        success: function(data){
            $('#id_opzione').html("");
            $.each(data, function(i, item){
                var id = item.id;
                var parent_id = item.parent;
                var nome_opzione = item.nome_opzione;
                var nome_parent = item.nome_parent;
                $('#id_opzione').append('<option data-opzione="'+ item.nome_parent +'" data-parent="'+ item.parent +'" id="' + item.nome_opzione +'" value="' + item.id + '">' + item.nome_opzione +'</option>');

            });

    });
    $('#id_opzione').on('change', function(){
                  alert('Changed');
                    var parent = $('#id_opzione').find(':selected').data('parent');
                    var nome_parent = $('#id_opzione').find(':selected').data('opzione');
                    if(parent != null) {
                        $('#parent-div').append('<label for="parent-div" class=" control-label col-md-4 text-left">'+ nome_parent +'</label><div class="col-md-6"><input type="text" name="valore_parent" class="form-control"></div><div class="col-md-2"></div>');
                    } else {
                        $('#parent-div').hide('fast');
                    }

                });
        }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Great, many thanks! I just added another <div> with id="prova to append new div and this work as well